# how to show TextBox in react native to display HTML content in textbox like <img> with Text?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios

i working on messaging mobile app in react native which uses data from backend using web services.
now i have to add stickers and smilies which are in png formate.
using this user can pick that emojis and add in text box and write text as user wants then sent it on send button.
when i receive that message it comes in string like. `string:<img src=="url of image">message text`

but as in react native there is no possible in text input to show images in html formate.
is there any third party library or something to show html text box like web application here is the screen shots of web application. i want to show text input in mobile app like in web application.

this smilies is custom png smilies and that smilies i need to use in mobile app.
i am stuck here please i need solution?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html

Comment: But, honestly, if you want to create "meme" images, you probably want to use a canvas https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas or some imaging library to stitch the text over the image.